# bash chdir history?

Tags: bash

I know I can `pushd` / `popd` if I want to save the current location before `chdir` into another directory. In bash I can go back to the directory before the last `chdir` by:

```
$ chdir /somedir
$ chdir -
```

I'm wondering if I can go back for several steps (`chdir ----` maybe??), just using `chdir` rather than `pushd` / `popd`, in bash is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

Comment: You can always write a shell function wrapper around chdir that checks if the argument is multiple dashes and then calls popd, while dumping the stack contents to /dev/null.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that `pushd` saves directories on a stack, so it can have multiple directories saved?

You can skip around using a command such as:

```
pushd +3; popd
```

Comment: You can even use `alias cd=pushd`, to avoid having to type the extra characters in `pushd`.

Comment: Thanks, but pushd prints the annoying stack contents, and, BTW won't it be blown up if pushd too many times?